# service php54w restart on centos 6.5

Tags: php, restart, centos6.5

I upgraded the php version to 5.4 following [this](https://webtatic.com/packages/php54/) guide but it
seems I cant restart the service
i tried

```
sudo service php restart
sudo service php54 restart
sudo service php54w restart
sudo service php-fpm restart (this worked on my 5.3.3 php version earlier)
sudo service php5-fpm restart
```

Anyone can help with the right command. I searched for it but found nothing
unfortunately.

Thanks.

Comment: php is not a service. it's an apache module and a standalone executable. it is not "always running", EXCEPT within apache.

Comment: I have installed nginx.  After I upgraded the php version the php files stopped working. So that's why I tried to restart php

Comment: Try doing `service --status-all `, that should print the services centos knows about. You could also list all service names by doing `ls /etc/init.d` and looking for anything relating to php